# How to define the datatype of a parameter in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, environment-variables

How can I define the parameter data type in TypeScript?

Whenever I define the data type, see in the code below (line 4), it gives me a syntax error:

```
const env1:any=require("./config")
const Sequelize:any = require('sequelize');

module.exports =  new Sequelize(env1.Variable.DATABASE_URL :any, {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  operatorsAliases: false,

});
```

Whenever I don't define the data type, it gives me the error shown in the below.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9ypa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is not type-related, rather the value you are passing as the database URL is `undefined`. Check the whether `env1.Variable.DATABASE_URL` has the correct value, which should be a string.

A `console.log(env1.Variable.DATABASE_URL);` should do the trick.

```
const env1 = require("./config")
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

console.log("DATABASE URL", env1.Variable.DATABASE_URL);

module.exports = new Sequelize(env1.Variable.DATABASE_URL, {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  operatorsAliases: false,
});
```

Good luck.